# Rewriting HTTP request contents that are going through Mikrotik RouterOS VPN

Tags: vpn, proxy, scripting, mikrotik

I need to pipeline through all the requests from my VPN clients connected to Mikrotik OpenVPN gateway, but when request being made is and HTTP request and is targeting particular destination, I want to rewrite some parts of the requests.

Does Mikrotik scripting allow such request manipulations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MikroTik cannot do what you ask directly.

You can match the requests based on the protocol and destination address and send them (dst-nat) to another server that runs some proxy that will modify whatever you want.